# Changing the attribute behind a legend without changing the symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, symbology, legend

I have a geology layer with a very large legend that was painstakingly created based on a geological code.  I now have a new attribute which is a friendly description for each code and I would like the legend to use (or simply display) the description instead of the geological code.  How can I do this without recreating the legend by hand?

Comment: Would you be willing to do this by Code? I did something just like this, for an LULC rater

Comment: @Devdatta, It may be that 'do it by hand' and 'do it by code' are the only answers, so if you have a code solution to share it may be worth posting.  I my case I'll probably suck it up and bribe an intern into doing it for me.

Comment: Sounds like something that ArcPy.mapping *should* be able to do - perhaps start by looking at the LegendElement object: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000041000000.htm  I'm not certain that ArcPy.mapping has the functionality to be able to swap the field being used by a legend item so please just treat as a suggestion.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I agree it _should_, but it looks like it doesn't. Neither the Layer object, nor the LegendElement object provide any access to the renderer.  The closest the LegendElement object gets is providing a readonly list of item names. Thanks for the idea, it was worth checking on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C# snippet did the trick (in the OnClick() method of a Button AddIn):

```
const string CodeField = "SMUcode";
const string DescriptionField = "SMUdetails";

IGeoFeatureLayer layer = ArcMap.Document.SelectedLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
IUniqueValueRenderer renderer = layer.Renderer as IUniqueValueRenderer;
IDisplayTable table = layer as IDisplayTable;
IFeatureCursor cursor = table.SearchDisplayTable(null, false) as IFeatureCursor;
int indexCodeField = cursor.Fields.FindField(CodeField);
int indexDescriptionField = cursor.Fields.FindField(DescriptionField);
//loop through each feature creating a dictionary mapping codes to descriptions
//code and descriptions should match 1 for 1, but if not, the last description
//for a code value will be used.
var descriptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
IFeature feature = cursor.NextFeature();
while (feature != null)
{
    string code = feature.Value[indexCodeField] as string;
    string description = feature.Value[indexDescriptionField] as string;
    descriptions[code] = description;
    feature = cursor.NextFeature();
}

//loop through the renderer changing each value
//Assumes descriptions are unique
renderer.Field[0] = DescriptionField;
for (int i = 0; i < renderer.ValueCount; i++)
{
    string code = renderer.Value[i];
    // change the label
    renderer.Label[code] = descriptions[code];
    //Change the value of the renderer item.  
    renderer.Value[i] = descriptions[code];
}
```